# Is it possible to define a custom ExternalLinkFilter in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, teamcity, azure-devops

I see that is possible to [Create a custom link type](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/link-type-element-reference#create-a-custom-link-type-tfs) however this seems to be restricted to work relationships, I would like instead to define a link to a an external resource, is this possible?

**Background**

I would like to develop a TFS extension that will allow TFS Work Items to be linked to TeamCity builds, similar to the way it is described by  [Automatic linking work items to builds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/25/automatic-linking-work-items-to-builds/) for TFS Builds.

Specifically I would like to create a new **type of external link** and write a plugin that supports entering a TeamCity build id and display the build number, status, date & time and link on the TFS Work Item.

This link type would allow a user to enter the TeamCity build id (or url) on the Work Item form as well as allow third party applications to add/remove this type of links pro grammatically via API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. External link types are all **system-defined** and support linking work items to other objects. If you just want to link TeamCity build on the TFS Work Item, you can use the **Hyperlink** type to link a work item to a build URL. See [External link types](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/link-type-element-reference#external-link-types) for details.

Another way is link Team Foundation Work Items with build in TeamCity. Since TeamCity 10.0, Team Foundation Work Items tracking is integrated with TeamCity. See this link for details : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Team+Foundation+Work+Items

> **Integration**
>
> By default, the integration works the same way as the
> other issue tracker integrations: you need to mention the work item ID
> in the comment message, so the work items can be linked to builds and
> the links will be displayed in various places in the TeamCity Web UI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I though this was likely to be the case. Hyperlinks are an option but not an elegant one IMHO as I would like to the info about the build (number, date, etc.) to be more prominent than what can be displayed with Hyperlink comments.
I suppose another option would be to create a custom control